# Recurrence Relation with multiple variables

Tags: analysis, recurrence-relations, recursion

Consider the following recurrence relation with two variables and similar bounding conditions:

\begin{align*}
    x_{1,t} &= \frac{1}{2-\frac{2}{n}} x_{1,t-1} + \frac{1}{2} x_{2,t-1} \\
    x_{i,t} &= \frac{1}{2} x_{i-1,t-1} + \frac{1}{2} x_{i+1,t-1} & 1 < i < n \\
    x_{n,t} &= \frac{1}{2} x_{n-1,t-1} + \frac{1}{2-\frac{2}{n}} x_{n,t-1}
    \end{align*}

$x_{i,0} = 1 $ for all $1 \leq i \leq n$.
Is there any standard method to solve these?

Comment: do you know [Markov Chains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain) ?

Comment: Yes, but $\frac{1}{2-\frac{2}{n}}$ is larger than $\frac{1}{2}$ and hence it's not stochastic anymore.

Comment: well, then you are going to have non-stochastic vectors $x$. The principle of having a vectorial recurrence $\bf{ x}(t)= \bf M \bf {x}(t-1)$ remains.

Comment: That's true but this matrix has a strange behavior I cannot predict (it's pretty hard to calculate). That's why I'm asking for a different solution :-)

Comment: That's why it is recommended that OP indicates what he has done and what is the obstacle. In fact, even for small $n$ the matrix diagonalize "strangely". So you have better to reformulate your post asking on how to diagonalize that matrix.

Comment: Sorry for that! But way do you think that a diagonalization of that matrix helps?

Comment: I got it :-) Yeah, but the eigenvalues and eigenvectors are somewhat strange...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your system reads as
$$
{\bf x}(t) = {1 \over 2}\;\left( {\matrix{
   {1 + {1 \over {n - 1}}} & 1 & 0 &  \cdots  & 0  \cr 
   1 & 0 & 1 &  \cdots  & 0  \cr 
    \vdots  &  \ddots  &  \ddots  &  \ddots  &  \vdots   \cr 
   0 &  \cdots  & 1 & 0 & 1  \cr 
   0 &  \cdots  & 0 & 1 & {1 + {1 \over {n - 1}}}  \cr 
 } } \right)\;{\bf x}(t - 1)
$$

So it is a random walk, with a stop at the ends, and with the 
immission (always at the ends) of a influx 
given as constant percentage increase of the population therein.
And the increase percentage lowers at growing of the vector dimension.

Since the matrix diagonalization is not neat, you are probably looking for 
an approximation. If so with respect to what ?

*-- reply to your comment --*

The matrix above (call it $\bf M$) is symmetric, either wrt the diagonal and wrt the antidiagonal , i.e.
$$
{\bf M} = {\bf M}^{\,T}  = {\bf J}\;{\bf M}\;{\bf J}
$$
where ${\bf J}$ is the [exchange matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchange_matrix).
Thus the matrix is [centrosymmetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrosymmetric_matrix) and in particular [symmetric tridiagonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix),
and only almost-Toeplitz symmetric.

As such:
 - $\bf M$ can be diagonalized by an orthogonal matrix $\bf Q$;
 - all its eigenvalues are real and distinct;
 - if $\bf v$ is an eigenvector so is its symmetric ${\bf J}{\bf v}$;
 - since $Q$ is orthogonal, it will contain the eigenvectors.

For an eigenvector we surely have that the ratio of the components is constant, and v.v. a vector for which the ratio remains constant must be an eigenvector.
A calculation for small $n$ reveals that the e.v. associated to the higher eigenvalue
has all the components positive and is in fact symmetric.
But I couldn't yet reach to a demonstration of that, nor of a bound in such a ratio.

Comment: Good lower and upper bounds for the values of $x_{i,t}$ would be nice. Perfect would be to prove that the ratio$(x_{1,t}/x_{i,t})$ is bounded by a constant for every $i$

Comment: I thank you anyway for your time and hints. Actually you could help me solving a different problem because I weren't familiar with the theory of tridiagonal matrices. Maybe I can still find something that helps me out here. Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: @Jannik: glad to have offered a minimal help. I could find on the net some papers dealing with the diagonalization of a symmetric tridiagonal matrix, but mainly relevant to the algorithms for that. But could not find yet a good analytical hint  about the  values of the eigenvectors